# Lua 'end' expected to close 'if'

Tags: if-statement, lua

I have this code here in lua

```
function onMouseDown(event)
    print(event.x, event.y)
    if event.x>160 then
        print("what")
        return 1
        print("whatwhat") 
    else 
        return 0
        print("WhatWhatWhat")
    end


    fruit:setX(event.x)
    fruit:setY(event.y)
end
```

But it is moaning that main.lua:59: 'end' expected (to close 'if' at line 56) near 'print' so it is expecting an end at the end of my if below print("whatwhat").
But I put an end there and it still moans at me if I do that.

I am pretty new to lua and I am a bit confused, I normally program in c#

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See the Lua manual [§3.3.4](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#3.3.4):

> The **return** statement can only be written as the last statement of a block. If it is really necessary to **return** in the middle of a block, then an explicit inner block can be used, as in the idiom `do return end`, because now **return** is the last statement in its (inner) block.

Your code has calls to `print` that occur after the `return` statement, and so is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your problem is the print after the return. That's dead code; Lua wants returns at the end of a block.